# Missing Array characters

Tags: json, forms

My form post data to a json file does not include the start and ending [ ] tags. And if posting to an existing json file to append it, it adds the data after the last ]. Also, then posted data does not include the requisite comma after the last curly brace in the entry.

Posting to empty json file (no [ ] tags)
Appending an existing json file containing [ ] tags

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = "sites/default/files/storage.json";
    $json_string = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string, FILE_APPEND);
    header('Location: thanks'); 
}
?>
```

I expected the JSON to be (for a blank file):

[
    {
       "name": "Joe",
       "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
       "cell": "1234567890",
       "dob": "1998-07-13",
       "study": "4"
    }
    ]

but it shows:

```
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
   "cell": "1234567890",
   "dob": "1998-07-13",
   "study": "4"
}
```

I expected the JSON to be (for an appended file):

```
[
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
   "cell": "1234567890",
   "dob": "1998-07-13",
   "study": "4"
},
{
   "name": "tom",
   "email": "tom@bloggs.com",
   "cell": "1234567891",
   "dob": "1998-07-16",
   "study": "9"
}
]
```

but it shows:

```
[
{
   "name": "Joe",
   "email": "joe@bloggs.com",
   "cell": "1234567890",
   "dob": "1998-07-13",
   "study": "4"
}
]
{
   "name": "tom",
   "email": "tom@bloggs.com",
   "cell": "1234567891",
   "dob": "1998-07-16",
   "study": "9"
}
```

Comment: How is your JSON looking alike?

Comment: Please clarify your question - the json output is shown above. Is there something else you're asking? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering what do you get at your PHP request before you convert it into JSON. I managed to ask for something else than the thing I was interested about. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem Lajos, well I don't know to be honest. I just see the contents of the json file is all.

Comment: You can check the requests sent to your server from your browser. In developer tools you can go to the network tab and check that out.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is what I found on the network tab: name=Tim&email=tim%40bloggs.com&cell=6618351553&dob=2019-04-24&study=5&submit=Submit

Answer (score 0):

If you were to run

```
$json_string = json_encode(array($_POST), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

you would get your desired result for an element. However, if you have already at least an element in the stored json, then you can store this as a JSON like this:

```
//Reading the file contents into a text
$yourJSON = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
//Decode your JSON into a variable, assuming it will be an array
$yourArray = json_decode($yourJSON);
//Adding $_POST to the array
$yourArray[]=$_POST;
//Encode
json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: I'll try that Lajos. Thank you, very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3642264 you are welcome. Please let me know the result.